# using python to create rdf triples and run queries

Tags: python, semantic-web

I've researched the entire web and this site. I'm having serious difficulties in beginning to use python for semantic web application. While there isn't alot of information out there, the book "Programming for Semantic Web" has code that is not only old, it doesn't even work ! I tried typing the fisrt set of code from the first chapter and I had no way of knowing what really happened.

Following was the code. The book says "To begin with, create a file called simplegraph.py." - Now, where the heck is the .py file ? And when I run this code, how do I call "run" or end it and see the output.

```
class SimpleGraph:
def __init__(self):
self._spo = {}
self._pos = {}
self._osp = {}
```

My ultimate goal is :

1.) To be able to create RDF triples using python
2.) Create Directed Graphs using python
3.) and then utltimately query the model so created.

Is there any step by step guide that can walk me through it without being vague?

Also, why can I run the code in IDLE (python shell)

running this

```
 from rdflib import Graph, URIRef
```

gives me the following error:

```
 raceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    from rdflib import Graph, URIRef
ImportError: No module named 'rdflib'
```

Comment: Did you install the rdflib first?

Comment: I sure did when I first installed python. I had troubles installing it but I had figured out a way somehow. How do I check its still installed.

Comment: The ImportError indicates the rdflib is not properly installed. Try re-install it see if that works.

Comment: now I cannot get the install to work "easy_install rdflib" gives "invalid syntax" as error

Comment: You are supposed to run easy_install in your terminal not the IDLE. Which OS are you using?

Comment: Yes, I ran it in my terminal on Windows 7, i closed and restarted and it worked

Comment: I don't think Windows support easy_install and I don't have a lot of experience with windows. You may need to search how to install python library in windows.

Comment: Why did I have to re-install it when I had it installed earlier. Do I need to run a command to save it? Also,  how do I proceed with the 3 things I need to accomplish. Is there a good reliable source for this other than that book